# How to display position of an element in an array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Have an assignment where I must sort a list of names and then display it. Then have the user input one of the names and searches the array and displays the ordered number in the array. I pretty much have everything done but I cannot get that part to work.

If I type in one of the names, it just returns the same name but doesn't give me the ordered number in the index. How can the code be changed so it correctly displays the number of the name that is input into the program?

```
def main():
    SIZE = 10
    names = ['Ross Harrison', 'Hannah Beauregard', 'Bob White', 'Ava Fisher', 'Chris Rich', 'Xavier Adams', 'Sasha Ricci', 'Danielle Porter', 'Gordon Pike', 'Matt Hoyle']
    searchName = str()
    index = int()
    selectionSort(names, SIZE)
    print('Sorted order:')
    for index in range (0, SIZE):
        print(names[index])
    searchName = input('Enter a name to search for: ')
    index = binarySearch(names, searchName, SIZE)
    if index != -1:
        print('The ordered number of this name is ' + str(names[index]))
    else:
        print(searchName + 'was not found.')

def selectionSort(array, arraySize):
    startScan = int(); minIndex = int(); minValue = int(); index = int()
    for startScan in range (0, arraySize - 1):
        minIndex = startScan
        minValue = array[startScan]
        for index in range (startScan + 1, arraySize):
            if array[index] < minValue:
                minValue = array[index]
                minIndex = index
        array[minIndex] = array[startScan]
        array[startScan] = minValue

def binarySearch(array, value, arraySize):
    position = -1
    first = 0
    last = arraySize - 1
    found = False
    middle = int()
    while not found and first <= last:
        middle = int((first + last) / 2)
        if array[middle] == value :
            found = True
            position = middle
        elif array[middle] > value:
            last = middle - 1
        else:
            first = middle + 1
    return position

main()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Your posted code has indentation errors, and you haven't shown the current and desired results.  "cannot get it to work" is not a problem specification.

Comment: Also note that your code should exhibit the problem without one of us having to supply information -- just hard-code what you currently have as user input.

Comment: Your `binarySearch` cannot return -1 to indicate "not in list". But – you can effectively debug it by printing out interim results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a simple, one-line change.
You get the name instead of the index, because that's exactly what you told it to print.  Instead, use this:

```
    print('The index of this name is ', index)
```

Your original went to the extra trouble to look up the name in that location.

Comment: Wow yeah you were right. Guess I was just overthinking it. Thanks!